# Docker 17.06-ce default container memory limit on shared host resources

Tags: docker

I have a host with a resource of 8 cores / 16 GB RAM.  We use `cgroup` to allocate `CPU` and `memory` for our custom application.  We tried to create a static partition resource between our custom application and docker. For example, we are trying to allocate the following :-

```
4 CPU cores / 8 GB RAM --> docker
3 CPU cores / 6 GB RAM --> custom_app_1

the remaining for OS
```

We have manage to perform the segregation for `custom_app_1`. Question is how I create a default limit memory and cpu to our container without having to use the flag `--memory` or `--cpus` for individual container.  I don't need to limit each container but I need to make sure that all containers running in the host cannot exceed the usage of 8GB RAM and 4 CPU cores, otherwise, it will be fighting resources with my `custom_app_1`

When i perform `docker stats`, each container is seeing 16 GB RAM, how do I configure so that they only see 8 GB RAM and 4 CPU cores instead

Comment: why don't you control docker daemon resources? https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html. I am assuming that it would limit overall containers launched. But I am not 100% on it

Comment: I have added `MemoryMax=1G` into `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file but still getting to see the container is taking entire host memory.  I use `docker stats` to check the memory usage and limit.  I would appreciate if some one can guide me on setting `cgroupfs` or to limit `dockerd` to use all the memory for the containers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So what you need to do is create a SystemD slice for the memory.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/limit-docker-memory.slice
[Unit]
Description=Slice with MemoryLimit=8G for docker
Before=slices.target

[Slice]
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryLimit=8G
```

Then configure that slice in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
    "cgroup-parent": "limit-docker-memory.slice"
}
```

Reload systemctl and restart docker

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

See the relevant section in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#miscellaneous-options)

### DEFAULT CGROUP PARENT

> The --cgroup-parent option allows you to set the default cgroup parent to use for containers. If this option is not set, it defaults to /docker for fs cgroup driver and system.slice for systemd cgroup driver.
>
> If the cgroup has a leading forward slash (/), the cgroup is created under the root cgroup, otherwise the cgroup is created under the daemon cgroup.
>
> Assuming the daemon is running in cgroup daemoncgroup, --cgroup-parent=/foobar creates a cgroup in /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/foobar, whereas using --cgroup-parent=foobar creates the cgroup in /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/daemoncgroup/foobar
>
> The systemd cgroup driver has different rules for --cgroup-parent. Systemd represents hierarchy by slice and the name of the slice encodes the location in the tree. So --cgroup-parent for systemd cgroups should be a slice name. A name can consist of a dash-separated series of names, which describes the path to the slice from the root slice. For example, --cgroup-parent=user-a-b.slice means the memory cgroup for the container is created in /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-a.slice/user-a-b.slice/docker-.scope.
>
> This setting can also be set per container, using the --cgroup-parent option on docker create and docker run, and takes precedence over the --cgroup-parent option on the daemon.

Comment: Thank you.  That seems to work fine! The daemon/dockerd correctly places container scopes inside given slices.  But one question, when i perform `docker stats`, I still see that it is utilizing the entire host memory.  But when i issue `systemd-cgls`, i do see the container that spin up falls in the parent group slice i have created.  Unfortunately from `docker stats` standpoint, it does not show it is using the limit.  Unless i'm missing something.  Although the parrent cgroup has memory limit, how do i really confirm it is actually utilizing that much and not go beyond ?

Comment: You can try and test is using this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99334/how-to-fill-90-of-the-free-memory

Comment: Thanks, the `stress` helps

Comment: Sorry to be bothering you, but the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` is broken as is, there shouldn't be a coma in it

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the case where `systemctl: command not found`? I think Ubuntu 14.04 uses Upstart instead of Systemd.

Comment: @DeanKayton, you can either replace upstart with systemd, that is possible for sure. Not sure if upstart supports memory limiting, you will have to check that out

Comment: You cannot replace upstart with systemd on 14.04... upstart supports memory limits but it does not do cgroups. I am not sure why your original answer involved systemd at all. It should be possible to configure the memory cgroup limits with docker itself.

Comment: @CameronNemo, yep you are right, I think you can only do it from Ubuntu 15.04+. For the cgroup setting this is to limit the docker itself within a cgroup instead of just the containers

Comment: Thanks a  bunch for this! I was able to throttle my Fedora workstation's CPU usage with [CPUQuota](https://gist.github.com/jpcaparas/95d6f81e70e7490713e60b2a484c32a4) (inspired by your answer). Was able to see throttling with `htop` and running the `while true; do true; done` command inside the container shell. I can see that it doesn't hover over 60%.

Comment: More details on the Slice schema at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html

Comment: Today I learned that in Ubuntu 18.04, the name `limit-docker-memory.slice` implies a Slice hierarchy. In order to correctly set the `cgroup-parent`, the value should be `/limit.slice/limit-docker.slice/limit-docker-memory.slice`.