# Limit the default number of CPU for each docker container using cgroups

Tags: docker, ubuntu, shiny, system-administration, shinyproxy

I was wondering whether there is a way to automatically limit the number of CPUs all docker container can use when running as by default, each container uses all the available resources.

When running the `docker run` command, I know I can specify the number of CPUs (`--cpus=`) but in my current case, the containers are started using another application (ShinyProxy) which does not allow me to specify this option.

I already spent a lot of time on this issue (e.g. using cgroups) but I haven't been able to set up anything working.

E.g, I tried to implement the solution proposed hereafter but I was not able to achieve any result.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46557336/8939750

Many thanks for your help,

Sylvain

Comment: have a look at the options and set whats needed https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer... unfortunately, this won't be working for me as I cannot use docker run (see the original post) because those are run using another software (shinyproxy).