# Default per-container memory limit

Tags: docker, cgroups

I would like to have a default memory limit for each Docker container.

I know I can use `--memory` when running a container. Yet the problem is the host is shared by many developers and I can't expect everybody to remember to do it.

I want the containers run without an explicit `--memory` parameter to be limited to e.g. `4GB` instead of being able to see the whole hosts memory.

I tried to setup CGroup limits as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46557336/1237617. The problem is that it's a limit on total memory used by all containers.

Can I setup a per-container memory limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to realize this by adding a proxy in front of docker service.
I use the proxy to inspect the JSON payload and modify the parameters to set the memory limit if it's absent.

The final step is to modify the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to point to the proxy.

`socat` might be useful if your proxy can't talk with sockets